# Loading Mapbox Style object from local json file in dash app

Tags: mapbox, plotly-dash, plotly-python, mapbox-gl

Trying to set a Mapbox style from a local JSON file in plotly dash app.

```
mapbox_token = <mytoken>

local_style=
json.load(open(application_root_path+r'/pages/campaignmap/mapbox_style.json'))


fig = go.Figure(
    go.Scattermapbox(
    mode="lines", fill="toself",
    lon=[-10, -10, 8, 8, -10, None, 30, 30, 50,
        50, 30, None, 100, 100, 80, 80, 100],
    lat=[30, 6, 6, 30, 30,    None, 20, 30, 30, 20, 20, None, 40, 50, 50, 40, 40],))

fig.update_layout(
    dict1={"mapbox": {"accesstoken": mapbox_token}})

fig.update_layout(
    showlegend=False,
    margin={'l': 0, 'r': 0, 'b': 0, 't': 0},
    mapbox_style=local_style
    )
```

Based on the documentation on the plotly website [Mapbox Map Layers in Python](https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-layers/) (see image below) this should work. The JSON file contains the export of the style from MapBox and it works fine when I use the service URL (second last dot point in image).

I've tried loading the JSON as string, dictionary and file path in the `mapbox_style` parameter with no luck.

Any ideas on how to make it load?

[image: Plotly documentation]

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the same things you've described and had no luck. I can provide a style URL and it works perfectly, but if I download that style and provide just the `style.json` representation of that same style, I can't seem to get Plotly to recognize it...

Comment: Experiencing the same thing.